# Как извлечь количество кликов по РК из API продавца Wildberries

Tags: python, парсер

Имеется личный кабинет продавца Wildberries. Нужно получить данные по рекламным кампаниям. Попробовал использовать API, но в документации ничего не сказано про клики. Было бы хорошо найти способ извлечь Exel файл, который можно скачать в личном кабинете или хотя бы разобраться с кликами

Comment: Нужен доступ в ЛК, чтобы понимать о чём речь.